# action-validation.xml in struts2 (open different pages when validation fails at different fields in validation.xml)

Tags: validation, struts2

I am working in struts2.

I have two fields in my `action-validation.xml`. I want if validation get fails at first field it will go to some jsp page (say `a.jsp`) and if validation get fails at second field then it will go to another jsp (say `b.jsp`).

As it always returns "input" when validation fails so currently I can target only one jsp page against it.

Answer (score 1):

void return types can't return anything

Did you design a work around?

Answer (score 0):

[Rich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828534/action-validation-xml-in-struts2-open-different-pages-when-validation-fails-at/830171#830171) is quite practicable if the logic is applied in the action being called on submit...

```
public String actionBeingCalledOnSubmit() {
  if(!isFieldAValid()) {
    return "DISPLAY_A";
  }

  if(!isFieldBValid()){
    return "DISPLAY_B";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create custom validation method in your action, return a custom resut:

```
public void validate() {
  if(!isFieldAValid()) {
    return "DISPLAY_A";
  }

  if(!isFieldBValid()){
    return "DISPLAY_B";
  }
}
```

Then in your struts.xml you will need to add the custom results:

```
<result name="DISPLAY_A">/a.jsp</result>
<result name="DISPLAY_B">/b.jsp</result>
```